# get a coordinates of object(component) in Sketchup( in ruby console)

Tags: ruby, sketchup

i have a question, how can i get a cooridinates (x,y,z) in ruby console of an object (component)? I need this cooridnates for send this coordinates to other object. Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much Sketchup activity at SO; you may have better luck at other forums, such as [SketchUcation](http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10142).

Comment: Maybe check that link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sketchupruby/9xCDs9qfBSo

Comment: This is an exciting question, and I hope to see more of it here.  Please post the answer to your own question, and accept it, if you find out.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - not much activity, but we still check it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

"A coordinate" is a little bit ambiguous, depending if you want a point from the bounding box, the insertion point or a vertex inside the component.

But a simple generic example would be:

```
# Assuming user has selected a ComponentInstance:
instance = Sketchup.active_model.selection[0]
puts instance.transformation.origin
```

---

> **ComponentInstance.transformationSketchUp** 6.0+
>
> The transformationmethod is used to retrieve the transformation of this instance.
>
> http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/componentinstance.php#transformation

---

> **Transformation.originSketchUp** 6.0+
>
> The origin method retrieves the origin of a rigid transformation.
>
> http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/transformation.php#origin